# How to retrieve HiddenField in ListView from postback page using masterpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have added a HiddenField control in an aspx page, but I am not able to retrieve the values in the postback aspx.cs. I am using masterpages. These code samples work outside of masterpages, however they must work using masterpages.

I am setting the value in the listview like so...

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" postbackurl="orderhistorydetail.aspx">View</asp:LinkButton>
```

I have tried using these two code snippets to retrieve the value in the postback aspx.cs page...

```
    foreach (string s in Request.Form.Keys)
    {
        Response.Write(s.ToString() + ": " + Request.Form[s] + "<br>");
    }
```

and...

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
    {
        s.AppendLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key]);
    }
    string formData = s.ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(formData);
```

Neither one of those code bits are retrieving the value. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tested locally, your code should work

Comment: @kblock I am using masterpages though

Comment: It shouldn’t matter, you have tried without a master page and it worked?

Comment: hard code a value in the hidden field to test.

Comment: I have used a hardcoded value and I have also placed another hiddenfield with hardcoded value outside of the listview and still nothing.

Comment: I have tried my examples above outside of masterpages and they work. Masterpages are the problem.